# Filtering layer using complex criteria?

Tags: geoserver

My Environment is PostGIS, Geoserver, and Openlayers3.

I've a PostGIS table which is published as a Geoserver layer. I need to filter its displayed features according to some complex filters (some complex queries on multiple DB tables). The user would select some criteria from a GUI, which will be used to filter that layer.

What is the best approach to do so?

I've the following (not complete) ideas:

1- Implement the filters as Geotools functions, then call these functions from the Style Document of the layer. But how to pass the user's criterias to these functions?

2- Implement the filters as Geotools functions, **then can I call these functions from WFS filters?** If yes, there is another problem which is the large size of layer's features, I prefer to display the layer as WMS rather than WFS.

3- Any other approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can publish a Geoserver layer based on a SQL View. SQL Views allow to define parameters which can be used to consider the user's choice. This works for WFS but also for WMS.

See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html for more details.

Comment: I need to figure out how to get this going... thanks for the reminder - that's a good project for next week (quiet!)